# How does google encrypt/obfuscate the http response to make it almost unreadable to the naked eye?

Tags: ajax, obfuscation

For any particular search google instant ajax return this:

```
{
    e: "tGj0TZ-XLaXh0QGyw7nuDA",
    c: 1, 
    u: "http://www.google.com/s?hl\x3des\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dque\x26cp\x3d3\x26pf\x3dp\x26sclient\x3dpsy\x26source\x3dhp\x26aq\x3d\x26aqi\x3d\x26aql\x3d\x26oq\x3d\x26pbx\x3d1\x26bav\x3don.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.\x26fp\x3daee70eb115de80e6\x26biw\x3d1440\x26bih\x3d653\x26tch\x3d1\x26ech\x3d4\x26psi\x3dWWb0TYasBu_q0QGW5IjmAg.1307862617656.1",
    d: "[\x22que\x22,[[\x22que\x22,0,\x220\x22],[\x22que\\u003Cb\\u003E es el amor\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x221\x22],[\x22que\\u003Cb\\u003Epasa\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x222\x22],[\x22que\\u003Cb\\u003E me dices\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x223\x22],[\x22que\\u003Cb\\u003E significa mi nombre\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x224\x22]],{}]"
} 
{
    e: "tGj0TZ-XLaXh0QGyw7nuDA",
    c: 0,
    u: "http://www.google.com/s?hl\x3des\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dque\x26cp\x3d3\x26pf\x3dp\x26sclient\x3dpsy\x26source\x3dhpx26aq\x3d\x26aqi\x3d\x26aql\x3d\x26oq\x3d\x26pbx\x3d1\x26bav\x3don.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.\x26fp\x3daee70eb115de80e6\x26biw\x3d1440\x26bih\x3d653\x26tch\x3d1\x26ech\x3d4\x26psi\x3dWWb0TYasBu_q0QGW5IjmAg.1307862617656.1",
    d: "" 
}
```

And with this response the page refresh the results. what kind of method google uses to accomplish this level of encrypt/obfuscate (Im not sure which term to use in this case)

Comment: This is not deliberate obfuscation, this is just normal character encoding.  Unless I'm very much mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing obfuscated about this. It is merely encoded so it can be transported in a JavaScript string without breaking it.

In JavaScript strings you can use escape sequences to represent characters: `\xFF` to encode a *ISO-8859-1* character and `\uFFFF` to encode a *Unicode* character. For example `\x3d` is the equals sign `=`, [`\u003C` is the less-than symbol `<`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c/index.htm) (internally, all JavaScript strings are Unicode).

You have two objects literals here which can be used to create actual objects. Try on the JavaScript console.

```
var test = {
    e: "tGj0TZ-XLaXh0QGyw7nuDA",
    c: 1, 
    u: "http://www.google.com/s?hl\x3des\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dque\x26cp\x3d3\x26pf\x3dp\x26sclient\x3dpsy\x26source\x3dhp\x26aq\x3d\x26aqi\x3d\x26aql\x3d\x26oq\x3d\x26pbx\x3d1\x26bav\x3don.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.\x26fp\x3daee70eb115de80e6\x26biw\x3d1440\x26bih\x3d653\x26tch\x3d1\x26ech\x3d4\x26psi\x3dWWb0TYasBu_q0QGW5IjmAg.1307862617656.1",
    d: "[\x22que\x22,[[\x22que\x22,0,\x220\x22],[\x22que\\u003Cb\\u003E es el amor\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x221\x22],[\x22que\\u003Cb\\u003Epasa\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x222\x22],[\x22que\\u003Cb\\u003E me dices\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x223\x22],[\x22que\\u003Cb\\u003E significa mi nombre\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x224\x22]],{}]"
};

console.dir(test);
```

yields (in Google Chrome)

```
Object
    c: 1
    d: "["que",[["que",0,"0"],["que\u003Cb\u003E es el amor\u003C\/b\u003E",0,"1"],["que\u003Cb\u003Epasa\u003C\/b\u003E",0,"2"],["que\u003Cb\u003E me dices\u003C\/b\u003E",0,"3"],["que\u003Cb\u003E significa mi nombre\u003C\/b\u003E",0,"4"]],{}]"
    e: "tGj0TZ-XLaXh0QGyw7nuDA"
    u: "http://www.google.com/s?hl=es&xhr=t&q=que&cp=3&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=aee70eb115de80e6&biw=1440&bih=653&tch=1&ech=4&psi=WWb0TYasBu_q0QGW5IjmAg.1307862617656.1"
    __proto__: Object
```

You could go on:

```
console.dir( eval(test.d) );
```